# Assign nested group to role in Azure AD Applications Users and groups

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Iv'e configured some roles types in Azure AD application manifest. When i assign a group X to the role i can see that the users in X are assigned. Now assume group Y is a group inside X. The users that are in Y are not assigned. Why? is there a way to make all the "inner" users to be also assigned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Not today. Role assignment only works with direct group membership. In a future release we will make it available for transitive group membership too.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! is there a due date for this release?

Comment: No due date yet. But stay tuned - leave me your email on the contact page of http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog and I shall ping you when we have an update. Does the unavailability of nested groups role assignment block your adoption?

Comment: @DushyantGill, is there any updates on this subject please ?

Comment: @DushyantGill When you say Transitive Group Membership, is this the same as having a Dynamic User membership type?