# Azure AD Graph API User IsInRole Nested groups

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I've followed this tutorial to create a role-based application:

- [MVC Role based authorization with Azure Active Directory (AAD)](http://www.russellyoung.net/2015/09/05/mvc-role-based-authorization-with-azure-active-directory-aad/)

In my Azure Active directory (AAD) (**Free Edition**):

- I've created a user : "Admin one".
- I've created a group: "Developers".
- I've created an application role : "admin" (using the application manifest).
- I've assigned the application role "admin" to the "Developers" group (using the graph api).

In my application, I can now use the `User.IsInRole` method to verify that my user got the application role "admin".

I wanted to test if this is going to work with nested groups so in my AAD:

- I've removed the "admin one" user from the "Developers" group.
- I've created a second group named "SubDevelopers".
- I've added the "admin one" user as a member of the "SubDevelopers".
- I've added the "SubDevelopers" group as a member of the "Developers" group (using the Graph API).

Now the `User.IsInRole("admin")` method return false for the "admin one user"...

Am I missing something, Is it possible to check role for user that are in nested group ? Is available for the AAD Free edition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**According to this post, this is not yet available ...**

[Assign nested group to role in Azure AD Applications Users and groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633510/assign-nested-group-to-role-in-azure-ad-applications-users-and-groups)